# Dask runs out of memory when a df was `dd.read_parquet`, but works fine when `from_pandas`... why?

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(n_workers=4)
```

Given a DF of some 63mm rows, with 3 columns `int64` and 2 columns `object` (strings under 10 chars long),

this:

```py
df1 = dd.read_parquet('..')
df1 = df1.repartition(npartitions=100)
df1.head()
```

... fails with `KilledWorker` error, after showing this:

```py
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

But then this:

```py
df2 = pd.read_parquet('..')
df2 = dd.from_pandas(df2, npartitions=100)
df2.head()
```

works instantaneously (I mean `head` does, the loading takes time of course).

I understand that the latter had entire df loaded into memory before giving it to Dask. But then what is the point of `dd.read_parquet`? I must be doing this wrong, just starting out with Dask.

UPDATE:

- memory limit 7.8GiB per worker
- parquet file is 914Mb on disk; not sure how to view disk usage by Dask, there are 4 empty directories in the temp folder
- this a single bare-bones EC2 machine with 32Gb RAM running on Linux, the only process is this jupyter notebook, so most memory should be available
- `cluster memory` part of the dashboard shows plot up to 32Gb; and `Bytes stored = 405.57MiB`
- not sure how to lookup memory per partition
- I don't insist on 100 partitions, but had exact same issue with single partition and 1000.

Comment: Please give details: how much memory do you give the workers, how big on disc and in memory is the data or each partition, how much memory is available to your main process?

Comment: @mdurant - updated 

Comment: @mdurant do you think this a bug that I need to bring up on [GitHub](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues)? Thank you.